# Pegar valor do JSON e definir comportamento AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Como pegar o valor do JSON com o ajax e definir o comportamento, de qual div e qual mensagem mostrar, por exemplo:

Se o JSON retornar `{"error":"true","message":"Algo deu errado"}` mostraria uma div qualquer, "error" por exemplo, com a mensagem que JSON retornou, sendo que **JSON pode retornar múltiplas mensagens**...

Outro exemplo de uso é apagar informações e "remover" a div com algum efeito de fade out, sendo o ID gerado automaticamente, ex: `<div id="item-52">`, se der tudo certo `{"error":"false","message":"Removido com sucesso"}` a DIV seria ocultada. Como posso fazer isso?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
                var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "teste.php",
                    data: dados,
                    success: function( data )
                    {
                        alert( data );
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma div com id errorMessage:

```
<div id="errorMessage" style="display: none"></div>
```

Depois mude seu ajax para:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "teste.php",
    data: dados,
    success: function( data )
    {
        if (data.error) {
            $('#errorMessage').html(data.message).show('slow'); 
        }
        else {
            $('#errorMessage').hide();
        }
     }
 });
```

Toda vez que ele fizer uma requisição ele vai checar o data.error, se o valor vier verdadeiro ele vai preencher a nova div de erro com a mensagem que veio e vai exibir ela pro usuário com efeito lento. Caso dê certo ele oculta a div de mensagens de erro.

Answer (score 1):

Tens de definir o comportamento através de condições dentro da função de sucesso.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "teste.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    if (data.error == "true") alert (data.message);
                    else $('#'+id).remove();
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

De qualquer forma, é mais fácil responder a uma pergunta do que escrever o código todo.